# Consuming GraphQL in C#. error: The HTTP request failed with status code InternalServerError{ "statusCode": 500, "message": "Internal server error"

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

Just wanted to check if someone can guide me on the problem I'm having.
I'm consuming a GraphQL from c#.Net. I'm using graphql client library and i am encountering an error:
The HTTP request failed with status code InternalServerError             `error`GraphQL.Client.Http.GraphQLHttpRequestException
`Error`"statusCode": 500, "message": "Internal server error", "activityId": "11111111111111"

Thing is, i am able to successfully run the consumption using Postman, but when I'm consuming the same query(Body) and header in C# i am unable to consume it. Below is my code

Running in Postman but not in C#.
Tried to use httpclient instead of graphql client and encountering the internal server error

```
    string apiUrl = "https://somedomain.com/api/employeedata";

        var graphQLOptions = new GraphQLHttpClientOptions
        {
           EndPoint = new Uri(apiUrl)
        };

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    
    var graphQLHttpClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(graphQLOptions, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer(), httpClient);

     //set header
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Sub-Key", "mysubkey");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer MyToken");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("CallBackURL", "https://mydomain/cust/empdata");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("InterfaceName", "employees");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("RequestID", "REQ001");
    graphQLHttpClie`nt.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Country", "US;UK;AUS");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("DeltaMode", "Y");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Region", "N");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("EmpType", "Permanent;Fixed");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContingentWorkerType", "Retail Partner");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("IncludeTerminatedWorker", "Y");
    graphQLHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("TerminationDateFrom", "2022-04-20");
   

    var request = new GraphQLRequest
    {
        Query = @"query {
                  employees {
                      errors
                      {
                          statusCode
                          message
                      }
                    employeeMain
                    {
                        employeeDataGroup
                        {
                            employeeID
                            name
                            workerType
                            employeeType
                            contingentWorkerType
                            hireDate
                            countryID
                            country
                            WorkEmail
                            terminationDate
                            nameGroup
                            {
                                fName
                                mName
                                lName
                            }
                            positionDataGroup
                            {
                                jobProfileCompensationGrade
                                location
                                locationID
                            }
                            supervisoryOrganizationDataGroup
                            {
                                superID
                                superOrganization
                                ManagerID
                                Manager
                            }

                            organizationAssignmentDataGroup
                            {
                                companyID
                                company
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }"
    };

    
    // Send the GraphQL request
    var response = await graphQLHttpClient.SendQueryAsync<EmployeeResponse>(request);
    
    
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure you http headers are exactly the same as postman.  I see three that may be missing 1) Content Type 2) Content length 3) User Agent.